# Devise - NoMethodError Undefined method `+' for NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Trying to reset password I get an error NoMethodError Undefined method `+' for NilClass. I guess it may be due to a devise method

```
def confirmation_period_expired?
      self.class.confirm_within && (Time.now > self.confirmation_sent_at + self.class.confirm_within )
end
```

because confirmation_sent_at still nil in db. I wonder why

```
def generate_confirmation_token
      self.confirmation_token = self.class.confirmation_token
      self.confirmation_sent_at = Time.now.utc
end
```

doesn't set confirmation_sent_at. No idea why, but generate_confirmation_token isn't called. Any thoughts?

Comment: what do this  `self.confirmation_token = self.class.confirmation_token` ?

Comment: Assigns a confirmation token. It's default devise method.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def generate_confirmation_token
 self.confirmation_token = self.class.confirmation_token
 self.confirmation_sent_at = Time.now.utc
 # you dont save your instance
 save
 # now saved
end
```

Comment: confirmation_sent_at is a field in database. How to initialize it?

Comment: use after_initialize callback in your model or set default value at db. I don't know how to put code:) http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: But I need not default value. I need a datetime when devise generate confirmation token. It suppose devise method to do so def generate_confirmation_token;
      self.confirmation_token = self.class.confirmation_token;
      self.confirmation_sent_at = Time.now.utc;
end

Answer (score 0):

Probably you got the error

```
 def confirmation_period_expired?
   total_sent_at = (self.confirmation_sent_at.nil? ||  self.class.confirm_within.nil?) ? 0.0 : (self.confirmation_sent_at +  self.class.confirm_within)
  self.class.confirm_within && (Time.now > total_sent_at )
end
```

you can also use `try`

Answer (score 0):

It was due the old version of Devise. In previous Devise versions (< 3.1.0), resetting the password automatically confirmed user accounts without sending confirmation. More here http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/